# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am getting the below error when fetching user which intern call a microservice to get album data. Album get request is working fine independently with direct IP address like -
`http://{ip address}/users/8cd8b369-fb6f-40d3-9c22-78505110b8de/albums`

but getting the below log in user microservice when getting a User data-
`http://localhost:8082/user-ws/users/8cd8b369-fb6f-40d3-9c22-78505110b8de`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgzmh.jpg)

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponseModel> getUser(@RequestParam String userId){

        UserDto userDto = userService.getUserByUserId(userId);
        UserResponseModel returnValue = new ModelMapper().map(userDto, UserResponseModel.class);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(returnValue);
    }
```

```
User Microservice log:
2021-06-27 17:15:57.305  INFO 2580 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2021-06-27 17:17:22.296  WARN 2580 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported]
2021-06-27 17:17:32.533  WARN 2580 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported]
```

**Album microservice controller:** Which user is going to fetch data from

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}/albums")
public class AlbumsController {
    
    @Autowired
    AlbumsService albumsService;
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @GetMapping(
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public List<AlbumResponseModel> userAlbums(@PathVariable String id) {
        List<AlbumResponseModel> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
        List<AlbumEntity> albumsEntities = albumsService.getAlbums(id);
        if(albumsEntities == null || albumsEntities.isEmpty())
        { return returnValue; 
         }
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<AlbumResponseModel>>(){}.getType();
        returnValue = new ModelMapper().map(albumsEntities, listType);
        logger.info("Returning " + returnValue.size() + " albums");
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

**##User Microservice**

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=user-ws
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
```

**##Api Gateway ]**

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

#This is working fine: #

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri= lb://user-ws
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/user-ws/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/user-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\\{segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[2]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter

#The below route is going to be executed for http://localhost:8082/user-ws/users/8cd8b369-fb6f-40d3-9c22-78505110b8de#

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=users-ws-get-update-delete
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri= lb://user-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/user-ws/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[1]=RewritePath=/user-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\\{segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[2]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8082
```

Comment: The post man image looks like you aren't sending the content type header

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb . 
After i sent the content type application/json, got to know the actual error in portman reponse and fixed it. 
It was due to mistake of getUser function written above should have accepted path variable like below-
(@PathVariable("userId") String userId)
instead i made it (@RequestParam String userId) which was wrong.